# Servlet receives empty strings

Tags: java, android, servlets

I am getting one really strange error.

Basically what it is about is that I send number formatted as String from Android App like "421" to Java Servlet deployed on GlassFish server ,but when I was debugging I found that the servlet receives an string that has 3 empty chars, basically it receives an String with that number of empty chars that  was the length of sent string in android.

Server side

```
package Applications;

import Applications.AdminConsole;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name="/RQSRV", urlPatterns={"/RQSRV"})
public class RQSRV extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public RQSRV() {
    super();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.getOutputStream().println("Hurray !! This Servlet Works");

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.getOutputStream().println("Servlet Accesed");
    try {
        int length = request.getContentLength();
        byte[] input = new byte[length];
        ServletInputStream sin = request.getInputStream();
        int c, count = 0 ;
        while ((c = sin.read(input, count, input.length-count)) != -1) {
            count +=c;
        }
        sin.close();

        String receivedString = new String(input);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());

        Integer doubledValue = Integer.parseInt(receivedString) * 2;

        writer.write(doubledValue.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        AdminConsole cs=new AdminConsole();
        cs.setEnabled(true);
        cs.setVisible(true);


    } catch (IOException e) {


        try{
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            response.getWriter().print(e.getMessage());
            response.getWriter().close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
    }  
    }

}
```

Android Side

```
    package com.app.myapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DoubleMeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText inputValue=null;
    Integer doubledValue =0;
    Button doubleMe;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculate);

        inputValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNum);
        doubleMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doubleme);

        doubleMe.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.doubleme:

              new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        try{
                            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.104:8080/Requestor/RQSRV");
                            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                            String inputString = inputValue.getText().toString();
                            inputString = URLEncoder.encode(inputString, "UTF-8");

                            Log.d("inputString", inputString);

                            connection.setDoOutput(true);
                            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                            out.write(inputString);
                            out.close();

                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                            String returnString="";
                            doubledValue =0;

                            while ((returnString = in.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                doubledValue= Integer.parseInt(returnString);
                            }
                            in.close();


                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                 public void run() {

                                     inputValue.setText(doubledValue.toString());

                                }
                            });

                            }catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
                            }

                    }
                  }).start();

            break;
            }
        }

    }
```

I hope you can help

Comment: So the body of the request contains three whitespace characters?

Comment: I see that you define byte[] input = new byte[length]; but where do you set the bytes???

Comment: Yes, that much as was the length of sended string

Comment: @StefanBeike inside this  'while ((c = sin.read(input, count, input.length-count)) != -1)'

Comment: I edited the reading part into this  sin.read(input, 0, length); but same results

Comment: as i wrote i´ve edited it into  sin.read(input, 0, length); but the other think i saw is that lenght of content in request is same as lenght of sended string ,but number of aviable bytes in input stream is 0

Comment: maybe your while condition is wrong. take a look to the code at the end of that page http://www.coderanch.com/t/278406//java/Writing-input-stream-file

Comment: @StefanBeike yes but i tried to read whole content in one step( no while ) like i post upper , and it ended with same result. Basic problem is that content is in HttpServletRequest that came to to doPost method but nothing is aviable in inputStream,but i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Use sniffer, for an instance: wireshark, to capture the network pacage to see the real data sent, which is an actually effective method to find the root cause.